# GTest's output has no colors when built with cmake+ninja and executed automatically

Tags: cmake, googletest, ninja

I'm trying to configure CMake and ninja as a build system for my project. Except the app itself I have an extra executable for unit tests powered by gtest. I thought it would be nice to have them executed automatically whenever they are built. Here's how I made it:

```
├── build
└── source
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cc
    └── ut
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── gtest
        │   ├── ...
        └── ut.cc
```

source/CMakeLists.txt...

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (trial)
add_subdirectory(ut)
add_executable(trial main.cc)
```

...and source/ut/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(gtest)
include_directories ("gtest/include")

add_executable(ut ut.cc)
target_link_libraries(ut LINK_PUBLIC gtest_main)

add_custom_target(run_uts
                  COMMAND ut
                  DEPENDS ut
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
                 )
```

Now when I build it, i.e.:

```
cd build
cmake -GNinja ../source
ninja run_uts
```

It works fine except that the output is colorless. When I run the ut binary by hand, i.e. `build/ut/ut` I get nice green and red colors. The colors are also there when I use Unix Makefiles as a genrator for CMake.

Since I'm only learning CMake, is there something I missed or is it an issue with Ninja?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume your automated code runs a gtest executable and directs the output to a file. By default, gtest adds color sequences only when sending output to a terminal. In order to force it to add color sequences to output sent to a file or a pipe, run your test executable with the `--gtest_color=yes` [option](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#colored-terminal-output).

Comment: Well, actually my code puts the output directly to terminal, but your advice helped anyway! My best guess is that (according to this thread: https://github.com/martine/ninja/issues/174) ninja puts it to a pipe here. At least this explains why it workes with Makefiles.