# Can ctest display googletest console colors

Tags: cmake, googletest, ctest

I am building and running unit tests built with googletest inside a cmake project with ctest enabled

I run the tests with "ctest -VV"

but the test output does not color the "red" and "green"

[ RUN     ] [      OK ] [  PASSSED  ]

Does anyone know if there is an options to ctest to allow those colors to bleed through to the console?

Comment: Without knowing the way you added googletest to CMake nor your host environment, it's just a guess: Could this be duplicate to [GTest's output has no colors when built with cmake+ninja and executed automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888998/gtests-output-has-no-colors-when-built-with-cmakeninja-and-executed-automatica)? Can you give the googletest option `--gtest_color=yes` a try?

Comment: So I tried --gtest_color=yes and that didn't work... but some more googling led me to GTEST_COLOR=1, setting this in my .travis.yml made the tests appear colored... but on my command line it looks like this  1: ←[0;32m[ RUN      ] ←[mStringTest.Case,   this suggest that googletest might be incorrectly thinking I'm an xterm, when actually I'm running bash inside a windows command prompt

Comment: "export GTEST_COLOR=1" worked for me (on Ubuntu).

Comment: @Étienne It worked for me, thx!

Answer (score 19):

As the OP suggested, I added this line to my .bashrc and it worked:

```
export GTEST_COLOR=1
```

Comment: sadly, this doesn't work within the Windows Developer Command Prompt. `GTEST_COLOR` only seems to help when calling the Google Test runner manually; trying to use `ctest` still gives uncolored output :(

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you don't want to export any variable to global scope and only have colors in one ctest call. In that case use this single command:

```
GTEST_COLOR=1 ctest -V
```

Answer (score 7):

In cmake you can pass environment variables like that:

```
add_executable(testExecutable
        my_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testExecutable
        gtest)

add_test(NAME testExecutable
        COMMAND testExecutable)

add_custom_target(check
        COMMAND env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 GTEST_COLOR=1 ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}
        DEPENDS testExecutable)
```

run `$ make check`