# Can I force cygwin to show colors like dos prompt when running GoogleTest?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, googletest, ansi-escape

It is a fact that for terminals that support ascii escape characters, one can use those escapes to colorize a string as described here: [ANSI Color Specific RGB Sequence Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682537/ansi-color-specific-rgb-sequence-bash)

```
  std::cout << "\x1b[93;0m " <<  "  this will be colored text! " 
            << "\x1b[0m"     <<  "  this is back to default after reset \n";
```

My issue: on *windows*,  googletest by default runs and colorized a dos-prompt successfully, but will print gibberish characters when you try to use escape codes that work for Cygwin or Linux. Is there a way to force cygwin to show colors just as the dos prompt does? Or, conversely, to make the dos prompt show colors from escape characters *without forcing the user to install things and/or modify system files* ?

Note: this is a somewhat related question:
[GTest's output has no colors when built with cmake+ninja and executed automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888998/gtests-output-has-no-colors-when-built-with-cmakeninja-and-executed-automatica/28912380#28912380)

Comment: what is your terminal ? Bash command `printf "\x1b[38;2;40;177;249mTRUECOLOR\x1b[0m\n"` works for me on Mintty and Xterm

Comment: The terminal shows ascii colors just fine, but it does not show colors for a windows EXE that does show colors when run in a DOS prompt. The command you enter above will not show up colorized in a dos prompt.